# MongoDB - How can I get the size of a collection using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I'm writing a server side code using node.js, I'm trying to get the MongoDB collection size using count method which is not working.

This is my code

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var host =  "127.0.0.1";
var port = mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;

function getStock(name, callback) {

    var db = new mongo.Db("testDB", new mongo.Server(host, port, {}));
    db.open (function(error){
        console.log("We are connected! " + host + ":" +port);

        db.collection("stocks", function(error, collection){
            console.log("We have a collection");
            **var numOfDocs = db.collection('stocks').count()**
            **console.log("The num of  Docs in our collection is: ",numOfDocs)**
            collection.find({"name":name.toString()}, function(error, cursor) {
                cursor.toArray(function(error, stocks) {
                    if (stocks.length==0) {
                        //console.log("No Stocks found!");
                        callback(false);
                    }
                    else {
                        callback(stocks[0]);
                        //console.log("Found a stock -> ",stocks[0]);
                    }
                });
            });


        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.count()` is an asynchronous function, just like `.find()` is.

Try the following code:

```
collection.count({}, function(error, numOfDocs) {
    console.log('I have '+numOfDocs+' documents in my collection');
    // ..
});
```

The first argument to `.count()` should be a search query. Since you want to count all documents, I'm passing an empty object `{}` as a search query.

Comment: What about the size() method?

Comment: @user3502786 there is no `size()` method in MongoDB. You can use [.stats()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#stats) methods, but it's asynchronous too.

Comment: @user3502786 the thing is, all io-related methods in node.js are asynchronous.

Comment: Is it going to give me the same number?

Comment: Yes. But it'll give you a lot of other information.

Comment: So count will give me just an integer right? Hoe can i print the whole collection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59546/discussion-between-leonid-beschastny-and-user3502786).

Comment: To print the entire collection, fetch the entire collection.maybe you want to use some streaming lib for MongoDB though, if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

Since mongo 4, [`count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) is deprecated. You should use [`countDocuments()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) instead:

> MongoDB drivers compatible with the 4.0 features deprecate their
>   respective cursor and collection count() APIs in favor of new APIs for
>   countDocuments() and estimatedDocumentCount(). For the specific API
>   names for a given driver, see the driver documentation.

```
db.orders.countDocuments({})
```